# Django test with a model called TestCase

Tags: django, testing

I have a model called `TestCase` (I know....), and I'd like to test it in my suite of tests.

```
class TestTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.test_case = mommy.make('main.TestCase')

    def test_property1(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.test_case.property1, 'foo_bar')
```

Running my test, I get :

```
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'c' models in application 'nose': <class 'main.models.TestCase'> and <class 'nose.util.C'>.
```

How can I make these kind of tests pass without renaming my model?

Comment: You can do that when importing the modules: `from x import y as z`

Comment: I'm using `mommy` in my test. I'm not explicitly importing anything. :/

Comment: Maybe you can try `from django.test import TestCase as DjangoTestCase`.

Comment: @abrunet what are you talking about? I say about how you import Python modules in the beginning of your `test.py` file, not importing data.

Comment: Yep okay I got it wrong. Gonna try that =) thanks

Comment: @abrunet welcome, posted as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When importing a Python module, Python allows you to alter the imported name in order to avoid name conflicts:

```
from x2 import y
from x import y as z
```

Then you will be able to refer to the imported module x.y as z without conficting with the x2.y module.

Comment: Answer was obvious, for some reason, I wanted a way to change the way mommy import stuff (??? I'm tired). Thanks for your quick reply. =)